# LINUX MINT 19.3: Apps don't appear as opened in the panel if I take them to another workspace

Tags: cinnamon, workspaces, panel

That's the problem. If I take an app to another workspace, it doesn't appear as opened in the panel bar. I have enabled the Windows quick list applet and now I can reach them, but the icon on the panel will appear as closed, if I click on it it opens a new one. It happens the same if a take the app back from the original workspace. It disappears from every panel!

I leave an image with Nemo opened (switched from workspace 1 to 2) but in the panel appears closed.

Anyone knows whats going on? Thank you.

[image: Nemo opened but not in panel.]

My desktop enviroment: Cinnamon 4.4.8.
Applets i have ennabled: Calendar, Grouped window list, Keyboard, Menu, network manager, notifications, power manager, printers, removable drives, show desktop, sound, system tray, workspace switcher and xApp status applet.
I'll show some screenshots from the grouped window list options:

[image: General]
[image: Panel]
[image: Thumbnails]
[image: Context menu]

**EDIT:**

I don't have the window list applet enabled, I think I've never had it, and if I enable it I get a list of windows on the right side of the panel like the following screenshot (the ones that have a description). And that's not how I want it. I want the windows like the ones on the left side of the panel. I also include in the same picture the window list options, but as I said, I have never used this applet.

[image: Screenshot and window list options]

PD: reboot doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Is that Gnome? Gnome2? Cinnamon? Something else? If it's Cinnamon, have you added the "Window list" applet to the panel?

Comment: @terdon Sorry, it's cinnamon. And yes, I actually use the Grouped Windows List.

Comment: Hello. I do use Cinnamon. Thank you, I know about that option. But I want it to only show the windows from the actual workspace. And if a switch an app to another workspace, it's window to appear on the panel of the new workspace. I used to have it like that. idk why it changed.

Comment: then please [edit] your question and explain all this. Tell us you are using Cinnamon, and add a screenshot of the current options so we can see what you have enabled. Also tell us what version of cinnamon, that might be relevant. I can't reproduce your behavior on my machine: moving a window also moves its button on the panel as well. However, your screenshot is showing us a shortcut, why is that relevant?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but please show us the options of the "Window list" applet, not the "grouped window list", that's just the button that shows you the list of available windows. Also, try simply removing the applet and putting it back again. Does that fix it? Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: @terdon Check new edit.